# Fitting the closest coefficients in a system of millions of simultaneous equations?

Tags: problem-solving

I don't really know the correct terminology to describe this, but let's say we have many values of $(x_n, y_n, z_n)$. Also let's say that our description of 'many' means that $i$ ranges from $1$ to some number in the order of millions.

I would like to convert each value of $(x_n, y_n, z_n)$ to $(a_n, b_n)$ such that:

$$a_n \cdot(m,n,o) + b_n \cdot(p,q,r) \approxeq (x_n, y_n, z_n)$$

where $(m,n,o)$ and $(p,q,r)$ are constant (that is, the same for all values of $n$).

All numbers in this system are positive, and range from $0$ to $1$.

As I see it, the problem is to find values of $(m,n,o)$ and $(p,q,r)$ that could be used with suitable $(a_n, b_n)$ to produce the closest values possible to the set of ($x_n$, $y_n$, $z_n$). Some inaccuracy is expected so this should be a 'best fit', with some way of reporting how closely it fitted.

Here is an example of what I'd like to end up with (this was made by going backwards, randomly generating various $a_n$, $b_n$, $m$, $n$, $o$, $p$, $q$, $r$ that produces $x_n$, $y_n$, $z_n$):

Input:
$$ \begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & x & y & z \\
\hline
1 & 0.310 & 0.259 & 0.776 \\
2 & 0.222 & 0.189 & 0.71 \\
3 & 0.231 & 0.197 & 0.774 \\
\ldots \\
999999 &0.254 & 0.21 & 0.55 \\
1000000 &0.237 & 0.199 & 0.635
\end{array}$$

Output (along with some description of how suitably this fits the input data):
$$(m,n,o) = (0.311,0.252,0.411)\\
(p,q,r) = (0.134,0.122,0.796)\\
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & a & b \\
\hline
1& 0.758 & 0.555 \\
2& 0.433 & 0.652 \\
3& 0.425 & 0.738 \\
\ldots \\
999999& 0.683 & 0.313\\
1000000& 0.550 & 0.493
\end{array}$$

How should I approach this problem generally? Is there a name for this sort of problem? Are there any algorithms that are designed to solve this sort of thing?

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like a Least Squares (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) problem. Instead of presenting your problem as millions of equations, can you extend your question with an edit that gives 2 or 3 equations as an example?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and advice to read up on Least Squares - I've edited my question to be a bit more clear, with an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand correctly then answer to your question is:   No it is not always possible to express $\left(x, y, z\right)^t$in terms of fixed $\left(p, q, r\right)^t$ and $\left(m, n, o\right)^t$. For ex. $\left(1, 0, 0\right)^t$ and $\left(0, 1,0\right)^t$ fixed you cannot express $\left(0, 0, 1\right)^t =a \left(1, 0, 0\right)^t+b \left(0, 1, 0\right)^t$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as part of the problem I'd like to have an algorithm determine some $(m,n,o)$ and $(p,q,r)$ that best fits. I see what you mean that it may not be possible sometimes, probably I should also have a some output value describing how well it fitted too (I updated my question with that).